# Calling generic method with generic collection

Tags: c#, generics

I'm am just getting started with generics, and am confused by how to implement the following scenario.

This is my base class:

```
 public abstract class UnclaimedProperty
 {
     public abstract string Key { get; }
     public virtual void Process() { }
     public virtual void Process(string FileName) { }

     abstract public void WriteReport<T>(List<T> PropertyRecords, string FileName);
 }
```

In my implementations I would like to pass a concrete list to the override. something like:

```
public class PennUnclaimed : UnclaimedProperty
{
   public override void Process(string FileName)
   {
      var reportDollarRecords = new List<PennUnclaimed>();
      //add items here
      WriteReport(reportDollarRecords, "PennCash");
   }

   public override void WriteReport(List<UnclaimedProperty> PropertyRecords, string FileName)
   {
      //write report here
   }
```

}

I get error:

```
'PennUnclaimed' does not implement inherited abstract member
 'UnclaimedProperty.WriteReport<T>(List<T>, string)'
```

What would be the correct way to implement this?

Comment: depends on what you want passed to that method

Comment: It will be a List with a concrete type, and will be different for each implementation.

Comment: Will it be the base type or the type of the current class being implemented? will it be constrained?

Comment: It will be the type of the current class being implemented, and it will be constrained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, consider making the abstract class generic.

```
public abstract class UnclaimedProperty<T> where T : UnclaimedProperty<T> {
    public abstract string Key { get; }
    public virtual void Process() { }
    public virtual void Process(string FileName) { }

    abstract public void WriteReport(List<T> PropertyRecords, string FileName);
}
```

That way the implementation would look like this

```
public class PennUnclaimed : UnclaimedProperty<PennUnclaimed> {
    public override void Process(string FileName) {
        var reportDollarRecords = new List<PennUnclaimed>();
        //add items here
        WriteReport(reportDollarRecords, "PennCash");
    }

    public override void WriteReport(List<PennUnclaimed> PropertyRecords, string FileName) {
        //write report here
    }

    public override string Key {
        get {
            return string.Empty; //TODO:return key 
        }
    }
}
```

The constraint on the abstract class for the generic argument will allow it to be the type of the current class being implemented.